# I get error (linkeShowAjax is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load the page in div(data)

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:linkeShowAjax('/actions/company.php?id=14&amp;actions=view')" id="show"></a>



        $(document).ready(function () {
            function linkeShowAjax(link)
            {
                $("#pageview").html("Loading...");
                $.ajax({
                    url: link,
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#data").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }}
```

i use jquery v1.11.2 and it work with me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linkeShowAjax` is only defined in the scope of the `.ready` callback method. Move this function outside of this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         //whatever you want to do here
    });

    function linkeShowAjax(link)
    {
        $("#pageview").html("Loading...");
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            success: function(result){
                 $("#data").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@KJ Price is correct. I'd like to add that you could also use a less intrusive mechanism to handle anchor click using `data-` attributes

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-success" data-url="/actions/company.php?id=14&amp;actions=view" 
  href="#" id="show"></a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#show').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        linkeShowAjax($(this).data('url'));
    });
}

function linkeShowAjax(link)
{
    $("#pageview").html("Loading...");
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function(result){
            $("#data").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @mostafaamin: do you get any erorr?

Comment: @mostafaamin: you can replace `#show` by a common css class for all those anchors. Maybe `btn-success`?